# Making a Bluetooth Mouse with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, mouse

I'm trying to make a bluetooth mouse using Arduino. I will be using an analog 2 axis thumbstick as the sensor. I understand that it's possible to do this with the Arduino connected directly to the computer (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/mouse/). Would it be possible for the arduino to instead communicate wirelessly using bluetooth? The controller I'm interested in is here: https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1259.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With that specific board, yes you can.  According to [this review](http://www.lucadentella.it/en/2018/01/25/ble-con-bluno-beetle/):

> Bluno also supports the HID (Human Interface Device) mode. When running in this mode, Bluno simulates an input peripheral (keyboard, mouse…) connected via BLE.